# OUTER JOIN Syntax error in SQL statement "

Tags: mysql, sql

Could anyone help me understand why this query is not working?

> Modify the query to list all the products (product) and their associated category (product_category) if they have one. Otherwise, do not display a value (null) for the category.

```
-- SQL request(s)​​​​​​‌​​‌​​​‌​‌‌‌‌​‌​​‌​​​​​‌‌ below
SELECT P.name as PRODUCT_NAME, PC.name as CATEGORY_NAME
FROM product as P
OUTER JOIN PRODUCT_CATEGORY as PC on P.product_id =  PC.product_category_id
```

it keeps showing me this error:

```
Syntax error in SQL statement "                       
SELECT P.NAME AS PRODUCT_NAME, PC.NAME AS CATEGORY_NAME
FROM PRODUCT AS P
OUTER[*] JOIN PRODUCT_CATEGORY AS PC ON P.PRODUCT_ID =  PC.PRODUCT_CATEGORY_ID
"; SQL statement:
-- SQL request(s) below
SELECT P.name as PRODUCT_NAME, PC.name as CATEGORY_NAME
FROM product as P
OUTER JOIN PRODUCT_CATEGORY as PC on P.product_id =  PC.product_category_id
 [42000-200]
```

[image]

Thanks a lot

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I don't know. I have passed an assessment on codingame.com, but I think they use MYSQL.

Comment: Well you need to know, because the error will be specific to a RDBMS.

Comment: Possible duplicate: OUTER JOIN isn't a MySQL thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/how-to-do-a-full-outer-join-in-mysql

Comment: MySQL doesn't support `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: As mentioned, 'Outer join' isn't a thing. Someone needs a new recruiter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OUTER JOIN` is not valid syntax in ANSI SQL or any implementation I've used.

Here's a good reference: https://crate.io/docs/sql-99/en/latest/chapters/30.html#joined-tables

You can say `JOIN` or `INNER JOIN`. These are synonyms.

You can say `LEFT JOIN` or `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. These are synonyms.

You can say `RIGHT JOIN` or `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`. These are synonyms.

You can say `FULL JOIN` or `FULL OUTER JOIN`. These are synonyms.

You should see the pattern now. The words `INNER` and `OUTER` are optional keywords.

`OUTER JOIN` (without LEFT, RIGHT, or FULL) is not one of the choices.

I suggest to satisfy your recruiter, you use `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks. I have tested your answer and It works like a charm. Thanks for the reference I will used it for my future preparation :)

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I don't know if `OUTER JOIN` is synonymous with `FULL [OUTER] JOIN` in any DBMS... So `OUTER JOIN` should probably read `FULL OUTER JOIN` or simply `FULL JOIN`.

But regardless, you don't need a full join here. A full join would list categories without a product. You need a a left join.

```
SELECT p.name AS product_name,
       pc.name AS category_name
       FROM product AS p
            LEFT JOIN product_category AS pc
                      ON p.product_id = pc.product_category_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

as long as category null values are not allowed, then I think you should use inner join

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).